# Why "null" String is returned in String.valueOf instead of java null?

Tags: java

I was checking `String.valueOf` method and found that when `null` is passed to `valueOf` it returns `"null"` string instead of pure java `null`.

My question is why someone will return `"null"` string why not pure java `null`.

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

I am asking this because developer will have to check with `equals` method for `"null"` string and not like `stringObj != null`.

*[update]:* okay there were down votes for this question, I am not raising question in the api but in my current company there are lot of api which returns `"null"` string instead of pure java `null` that is why I asked this question to know whether is it a best practice to return `"null"` string if we found `null` string object.

Comment: That's just how it was spec'd to behave. Useful mostly for printing (and it is *very useful* that System.out.println doesn't error out if passed `null`)

Comment: Don't pass a `null` in the first place?

Comment: _"I am asking this because developer will have to check with equals method for "null" string and not like stringObj != null."_ If you're comparing Strings directly, just check the references. Otherwise it means that your equals method is based on the String representation of an object which is not good.

Comment: You can't print `null` but you can print `"null"`

Comment: You want a String from an object and you're confused when you get it?

Comment: @Thilo @Peter its not just of printing, I wanted to know whether its a good practice to return `"null"` string instead of `null`, I have updated my question a bit.

Comment: No, of course not. This particular case is in fact only for printing. If you want to indicate a missing value and be able to act on that later, return `null`, or use `Optional`. Or a NullObject. Or throw an IllegalArgumentException. Unless it is also for printing, it this case return the String that you want to print (empty string, "-", "null", "NULL", whatever).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Because `String.valueOf()` returns a `String` representation, which for a `null` is `"null"`.

The developer shouldn't be checking the return value at all, since it's meant for display purposes, not for checking whether a reference was null or not.

Answer (score 28):

You are looking for [Objects#toString(java.lang.Object,java.lang.String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#toString(java.lang.Object,java.lang.String))

The call

> Objects.toString(obj, null)

returns null when object is null.

Answer (score 1):

Because you only want a string representation of `null` and so it did. 
Purpose of this method is to return the String representation.

Check link [String.valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object))

Answer (score -2):

I would only use `valueOf` for displaying something directly. It doesn't offer robust enough validation and sanity checking to pass the output directly into a database, and could lead to incomplete data or data corruption.

Using the following query I discovered there were null-values in the columns.

```
Select * from tableName x where x.name is null
```

Comment: could not follow your SQL example? what you are trying to relate it with?

Comment: I'm just saying that I've tried queries before where I'm searching for null values, but have received none, because the word "null" was in the column where I was expecting a null value. This is why I discourage using string.valueOf for placing the result into a database table.

Comment: I didn't realize that another user could directly edit my comment here. This seems like an issue, given the sentiments in the comment get attributed to me, rather than who edited it. Sure you can look at the edits, but from first glance it appears I wrote the comment, though it was change rather significantly from my original comment.