# Empty/NULL Short value in object, returns non-empty String, is this intended?

Tags: java, string

With this class:

```
public class ShortValue {

    private Short code;

    public Short getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(Short code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

Below code:

```
    ShortValue s = new ShortValue();
    String test = String.valueOf(s.getCode());
    System.out.println("value: " + test + ", length: " +  test.length());
    System.out.println(s.getCode());
```

will output:

```
value: null, length: 4
null
```

Meaning actual string "null" is being created here from empty short value.

Is this intentional that empty short value returns a non empty String? What is the purpose of this in Java?

I am not complaining about the behavior though. Intuitively or naively, I had assumed that uninitialized short value would result in empty String if I get a String value from it where needed, but instead it returned string "null", so I am only trying to see where this would make sense or if it is largely a part of some default behavior of JVM that I am not aware of.

Comment: Null is not the same as empty. `String.valueOf(null)` returns `"null"`.

Comment: @shmosel System.out.println(String.valueOf(null)); throws a NullPointerException

Comment: My bad, it's calling the wrong overload. Try `String.valueOf((String)null)`.

Comment: *I had assumed that uninitialized short value would result in empty String...* You don't have to assume; it's spelled out in the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-java.lang.Object-

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou yes https://stackoverflow.com/a/33891982/3476492